# Unable to locate element for a website

Tags: html, selenium

Unable to inspect search label in www.walmart.com website. Any help much appreciated.

tried using css , id , etc but nothing helped. All the below code i tried but it didn't helped.

```
driver.findElement(By.id("global-search-input")).sendKeys("asifalikhan786@gmail.com");
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='global-search-input']")).sendKeys("dssss");
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input[placeholder = 'Search']")).sendKeys("adahadha");
```

Answer (score 0):

I looked at the page's code and noticed that By.id cannot work, because the object you want to access has no id.
I suggest you to try this:

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.className("eader-GlobalSearch-input"));
element.clear();
element.sendKeys("your text");
```

Comment: Can some else check and tell if frame is needed? I am a newbie here

Comment: Can anyone please help here.

Comment: I did tried the code I sent you, and it worked. Can you try it again, then post your entire @Test method and your error log?